# Script con do While cuelga pestaña de navegador

Tags: javascript, jquery, script, while

Tengo un script, que dado el id de un album cualquiera de la tienda de iTunes store (se lo paso a la función), llama a la API pública de búsqueda de itunes y lo busca en distintas tiendas (una tienda x país) hasta que lo encuentra en alguna de estas tiendas (las tiendas están en array), también termina la ejecución del script si se termina el array y no hubo ninguna coincidencia, para esto decidí usar un ciclo do while (que recorre el array), veo que el script cuelga la pestaña del navegador, no sé si está fallando mi lógica del condicional o que es lo que está provocando esta situación.

A continuación el código:

```js
let isocodes = [
                {"Code": "US", "Name": "United States"},
                {"Code": "AF", "Name": "Afghanistan"},
                {"Code": "DW", "Name": "Tienda de itunes Inexistente (Fake)"},
                {"Code": "AL", "Name": "Albania"},
                {"Code": "DZ", "Name": "Algeria"},
                {"Code": "AD", "Name": "Andorra"},
                {"Code": "AO", "Name": "Angola"},
                {"Code": "AI", "Name": "Anguilla"},
                {"Code": "AG", "Name": "Antigua and Barbuda"},
                {"Code": "AR", "Name": "Argentina"},
                {"Code": "AM", "Name": "Armenia"},
                {"Code": "AU", "Name": "Australia"},
                {"Code": "AT", "Name": "Austria"},
                {"Code": "AZ", "Name": "Azerbaijan"},
                {"Code": "BS", "Name": "Bahamas"},
                {"Code": "BH", "Name": "Bahrain"},
                {"Code": "BD", "Name": "Bangladesh"},
                {"Code": "BB", "Name": "Barbados"},
                {"Code": "BY", "Name": "Belarus"},
                {"Code": "BE", "Name": "Belgium"},
                {"Code": "BZ", "Name": "Belize"},
                {"Code": "BJ", "Name": "Benin"},
                {"Code": "BM", "Name": "Bermuda"},
                {"Code": "BT", "Name": "Bhutan"},
                {"Code": "BO", "Name": "Bolivia, Plurinational State of"},
                {"Code": "BA", "Name": "Bosnia and Herzegovina"},
                {"Code": "BW", "Name": "Botswana"},
                {"Code": "BR", "Name": "Brazil"}];



encontrar(1440893510);

function encontrar(tid) {

  let sigue = false;
  let indice = 0;
  do {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://itunes.apple.com/lookup',
      data: {
        id: tid,
        media: 'music',
        entity: 'song',
        country: isocodes[indice].Code
      },
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      error: function(error) {
      console.log('Borrar Tienda iTunes Store Inválido o Inexistente ' + isocodes[indice].Name);
      /*throw new Error(error.errorMessage);*/
       // console.log(error);
                                        },
      success: function(data) {

        if (data.resultCount > 0) {
          console.log('Encontrado en ' + isocodes[indice].Name);
          sigue = true;
        } /* else if (data.errorMessage) {
          console.log('Borrar Tienda iTunes Store Inválido o Inexistente  ' + isocodes[indice].Name);
        }*/ else {
          console.log('No encontré nada con ' + isocodes[indice].Name);
        }
        indice++;
      }
    });

  } while (!sigue && indice < isocodes.length);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[**FUNCIÓN ENCONTRAR CON FOR, FUNCIÓN SÍNCRONA SUGERIDO POR JUAN**](https://jsfiddle.net/nkbye4Lw/)

Comment: Da la sensación  de que se cuelga ya que seguramente itunes cada X peticiones te haga esperar un tiempo (para que no le sobrecargas el sistema) y tu programa debe de quedarse esperando. Para comprobar eso haz 2 peticiones, un sleep, 2 peticiones, etc

Comment: Pista: **¡manejo de errores!**

Comment: @ICIM comprobado, usé un array con solo 2 países y sigue lo mismo, ademas esta misma petición, ya la he hecho funcionar sin do while (creando una función que se autollama si no obtiene resultado), el caso es que termina de comprobar todo el array, sin dificultades de número de peticiones.

Comment: Tiene razón padaleina y juan-carlos. Mi error fue no usar tu código para ejecutar y usar una llamada asincrona. Por ese motivo me falló la llamada cuando la realize. Efectivamente es el ajax dentro de do-while

Comment: @padaleiana Gracias, pero no sé a que te refieres con manejo de errores.

Comment: En el ajax, manejas el _success_; ¿y si hay errores en la petición? Deberías manejarlo con _error_, el cual es un [evento de Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/).

Comment: Saludos. Verifica, `indice` solo lo incrementas cuando el Ajax fue exitoso; prueba usando en vez de `success` que sea `complete` donde lo incrementes; u otra opción es que no lo incluyas con el Ajax sino fuera de este, es decir, antes de evaluar con el while; desde luego deberás remover `indice++;` donde esta actualmente para hacer el cambio no afecte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que has metido un `ajax` al `do-while` y la ejecución de éste es asíncrona, es decir, que el `ajax` se ejecuta y sigue con la siguiente instrucción mientras se procesa el servicio. Como el índice se incrementa cuando se retorna del `ajax`, entonces, lo que está hacendo es ejecutando nuevamente el ajax con el mismo indice que el anterior y aquí viene el loop infinito por el do-while hace el ciclo rapidamente y no da oportunidad a que retornen las funciones.

**ALTERNATIVA 1: LLAMADA SINCRONICA CON FOR-LOOP**

La primera versión no funcionaba debido al `datatype`. El `jsonp` no soporta llamadas síncronasm, por lo tanto, el parametro `async: false` se ignoraba.

Colocando `datatype: 'json'` se corrige el problema. La verdad no uso `jsonp` por lo que no sabía de este comportamiento.

```
let stop = false;

encontrar(1440893510);
 function encontrar(tid) {
                
 for(let indice=0; indice<isocodes.length; indice++) {
    console.log(stop);
   console.log(indice);
   if (!stop) {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'https://itunes.apple.com/lookup',
      data: {id: tid, media: 'music', entity: 'song', country: isocodes[indice].Code},
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      error: function(error) {

                                                console.log('Borrar Tienda iTunes Store Inválido o Inexistente ' + isocodes[indice].Name);
                                                // console.log(error);
                                        },
      success: function (data) {
         if (data.resultCount > 0){
                                                        console.log('Encontrado en ' + isocodes[indice].Name);
                                                        stop = true;
         }/*else if (data.errorMessage){
                                                        throw new Error(data.errorMessage)
                                                        console.log('Borrar Tienda iTunes Store Inválido o Inexistente ' + isocodes[indice].Name);

          }*/ else {
          console.log('No encontré nada con ' + isocodes[indice].Name);
                                                }

                                        }
          })
          } else {
             break;
          }


          }
      }
```

**ALTERNATIVA 2: LLAMADO ASÍNCRONO UTILIZANDO RECURSIVIDAD**

Aquí el llamado ajax es asíncrono y en cada devolución se evalua si se encontró el resultaqdo, si es así sale de la recursión de lo contrario, vuelve a ejecutarse la función.

Cabe señalar que, esta alternativa es mejor que la anterior puesto que el parametro `async` será obsoleto en futuraqs vesiones JQUERY.

```
var indice=0;
var id;
 function encontrar(tid)
{
    id=tid; 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://itunes.apple.com/lookup',
        data: {id: id, media: 'music', entity: 'song', country: isocodes[indice].Code},
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
            if(data.resultCount>0){
                    console.log('Encontrado en ' + isocodes[indice].Name);
                    // Información de la coleccion
                    for(var d in data.results[0]) {
                            console.log(d + " " + data.results[0][d]);
                    }
                    

                    return;
             }else{
                  console.log('No encontré nada con ' + data.errorMessage);
             }
            indice ++;
            console.log(indice);
            if(indice<isocodes.length){
              encontrar(id);
             }
           }   ,
        error: function() {
         indice++;
         encontrar(id);
        }});
}      


encontrar(1440893510);
```

Comment: Lo mencionado del tipo de ciclo, es la clave de lo que está mal en mi script. Sin embargo, intenté cambiando el parámetro para que la petición AJAX sea haga asíncrona, pero no funcionó, luego también cambié el ciclo por uno de tipo for y ya funciona, pero veo que encuentra un país válido y sigue buscando hasta terminar el array (obviamente le coloqué una banderilla), también me di cuenta que al parecer no recorre el array de objetos en el orden (suponiendo que quisiera dejar que busque en todas las tiendas mencionadas en el array) pues las respuestas en consola así lo evidencian.Muchas Gracias

Comment: Cuando invocas el `ajax` asíncrono dentro de una bucle, las peticiones se envían en orden pero no así las respuestas, por ejemplo, la petición 3 puede llegar antes de la petición 1.

Comment: La respuesta del servidor, no tiene nada del país, lo que sucede es que si yo hago la petición AJAX, con un país en el que iTunes no tiene tienda o ni siquiera existe ese país (porque me lo inventé solo para probar), la API responde con mensaje de error en "data.errorMessage". Ahora, la tienda puede ser válida (que son todas, excepto una del array, que me inventé) existen albums que solo existen para la tienda de determinado(s) país(es), entonces, si busco un ID en una tienda válida, arroja "data.resultCount " > a 0 si el album fué publicado para este país, si no lo está responde con 0 (cero).

Comment: publicaré el código que tengo ahora al final de mi pregunta, para si por favor, me puedes echar una mano, porque con el for sigue iterando el Array hasta terminar, con la banderilla. Lo que deseo lograr, es que la primera coincidencia válida ("data.resultCount" >  0 (cero)) deje de buscar, porque esto significa que ya encontró una tienda válida en la que el Album está publicado.

Comment: Esta ultima alternativa la he probado y funciona. Te agregue la información de la colección que retorna.

Comment: Me encontré que con el método del ciclo for, la búsqueda no se detiene, al encontrar la primera coincidencia,  porque la variable bandera "STOP", actualiza su valor  a TRUE solo dentro de la misma función anónima e la que se encuentra (se actualiza por valor, no por referencia), entonces la variable declarada siempre es FALSE durante toda la ejecución, y por lo tanto el Condicional IF, nunca llega a ejecutar las instrucciones del ELSE. Me preguntaba si se puede hacer algo para hacerlo funcionar correctamente este script con el FOR. Con función auto-llamables funciona, pero deseo sea con ciclos

Comment: Puedes ver mi código en el JSFiddle, la variable es Global para toda la función. La variable se resiste a ser modificada.

Comment: LISTO! las dos alternativas.

Comment: Sucede es que debo usar "JSONP", debido a que SOP (política de seguridad del mismo origen) prohíbe que se carguen datos de servidores ajenos al de la aplicación javascript. JSONP es un método que permite enviar datos estructurados en formato JSON entre dominios distintos y es lo que admite Apple. Si uso JSON desde un navegador distinto a Safari, el navegador bloquea la solicitud. Por tanto, vuelvo a la vieja confiable del llamado con funciones recursivas, que si funciona con código Asíncrono. Agradezco mucho la colaboración, y gracias a ti ahora aprendí algunas cositas que no tenia idea.

Comment: Bueno, la verdad que también aprendí lo del `json` . Es un gusto saber que pude ayudarte.